# AddLiquidity to pool: Uniswap V3 Pool Deployer and PoolAddress.computeAddress() make different pool addresses

Tags: uniswapv3

I have deployed all UniswapV3 contracts locally in a Foundry test, then tried to mint a new position following https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/guides/providing-liquidity/mint-a-position

I realized when I made a new pool by calling:
`nonFungiblePositionManager.createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(...)` , which calls

`PoolInitializer.createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(...)`, which calls

`pool = IUniswapV3Factory(factory).createPool(token0, token1, fee);`, which calls

`pool = deploy(address(this), token0, token1, fee, tickSpacing);`, which calls

```
UniswapV3PoolDeployer.deploy(...){
        parameters = Parameters({factory: factory, token0: token0, token1: token1, fee: fee, tickSpacing: tickSpacing});
        pool = address(new UniswapV3Pool{salt: keccak256(abi.encode(token0, token1, fee))}());
//pool address1
        delete parameters;
    }
```

Then I got a new pool address.
But when I tried to mint a new position by adding liquidity to that pool:
`NonFungiblePositionManager.mint()`, which calls

```
LiquidityManagement.addLiquidity(){
    PoolAddress.PoolKey memory poolKey =
    PoolAddress.PoolKey({token0: params.token0, token1: params.token1, fee: params.fee});
    pool = IUniswapV3Pool(PoolAddress.computeAddress(factory, poolKey));
//pool address2
    { (uint160 sqrtPriceX96,,,,,,) = pool.slot0();//failed here
  ... }
...
}
```

Then it failed because this pool address2 is different from the pool address1 !!??

A closer look at the PoolAddress library:

```
    function computeAddress(address factory, PoolKey memory key) internal pure returns (address pool) {
        require(key.token0 < key.token1);
        pool = address(
            uint256(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        hex'ff',
                        factory,
                        keccak256(abi.encode(key.token0, key.token1, key.fee)),
                        POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

Although removing POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH does not help, but why does Uniswap have this POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH?
Something is causing this address calculation not to match the `address(new UniswapV3Pool{salt: keccak256(abi.encode(token0, token1, fee))}())`

Why is that? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH is a hash on the UniswapV3Pool code. If you modified the pool contract's code in any way in your fork, then this hash won't match and you'll get issues like the one you described above. So either don't modify the code or calculate new hash and put it in your fork.

Answer (score 1):

you can determine POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH by yourself with this code:
bytes32 public POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(type(UniswapV3Pool).creationCode));
Which UniswapV3Pool is smart contract pool from uniswap-v3-core